# Scala's overloading and default parameter limitations: how to avoid writing down many combinations?

Tags: scala

I recently found out Scala does not allow multiple overloaded versions of the same method to have default parameters. I have a set of method overloads where an implicit parameter is needed if (and only if) one of the main parameters is specified. This would be the 'main' method:

```
def replies(after: Option[Post] = None, limit: Option[Int] = None)
           (implicit db: Instance, order: QueryOrdering[Post]): Stream[Post]
```

This fetches entries from a database with basic paging. If `after` is specified, only entries logically following it, according to `order`, should be retrieved. But I don't want to have to specify `order` for cases where `after` is not provided. But the following code is not allowed, as only a single overload can have default parameters:

```
def replies(limit: Option[Int] = None)
           (implicit db: Instance): Stream[Post]
  replies(limit = limit)(db, QueryOrdering.noOp)
```

I could write down methods for all possible parameter combinations:

```
def replies()(implicit db: Instance)
def replies(after: Post)(implicit db: Instance, order: QueryOrdering[Post])
def replies(limit: Int)(implicit db: Instance)
```

But this is bothersome, and prone to combinatorial explosion for more than 2 parameters. Is there a better way to model this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one has said "magnet pattern" yet?

[The magnet blog is here.](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/)

Everyone must be on a lunch break.

Then you control what implicits are available to package given combinations of args.

[Sample answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16886099/1296806)

[Or tersely.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186786/1296806)