# How to overload method with same signature, but with additional implicit parameters

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, mixins

Currently to add standard prefix to log in our Play application, I override LoggerLike trait with additional functions

```
trait MyLogger extends LoggerLike {

    ...

    def error(message: => String, error: => Throwable)(implicit myObject: MyObject)  {
        if (super.isErrorEnabled) logWithPrefix(encounterAware, super.error, message, error)
    }

    private def logWithPrefix(myObject: MyObject, log: (=> String) => Unit, message: => String) = {
        log(s"A:${myObject.A} ${message}")
    }   

    ...
}
```

And use it like this:

```
new Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getSimpleName)) with MyLogger
```

I expect this to affect only log entries which have implicit myObject in context, and leave all old references valid, but all my logs start referencing new method.

*I don't want to change the name of the method or provide default value for implicit.*

How do I need to declare error method, to get desired behavior?

Comment: You cannot overload with only implicits. The difference between which overload gets called cannot depend on whether or not an implicit is in scope.

Comment: And there is no way arround this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179229/scala-currying-and-overloading ; a solution is to use the "magnet pattern", e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646866/scalas-overloading-and-default-parameter-limitations-how-to-avoid-writing-down?lq=1